# How to force the current line to be always in the middle of the screen

Tags: display

I am editing a large file.  I would like the current line where the cursor is at to be always in the middle of the screen. Is this possible?

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, but maybe you don't know about this: you can use `C-l` to manually recenter.

Comment: `M-x scroll-lock-mode`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a mode for that:  `centered-cursor-mode`.  It can be installed from MELPA.

It does not play well with a couple of modes, so this is my configuration:

```
;; keep the cursor centered to avoid sudden scroll jumps
(require 'centered-cursor-mode)

;; disable in terminal modes
;; http://stackoverflow.com/a/6849467/519736
;; also disable in Info mode, because it breaks going back with the backspace key
(define-global-minor-mode my-global-centered-cursor-mode centered-cursor-mode
  (lambda ()
    (when (not (memq major-mode
                     (list 'Info-mode 'term-mode 'eshell-mode 'shell-mode 'erc-mode)))
      (centered-cursor-mode))))
(my-global-centered-cursor-mode 1)
```

As @Nsukami mentioned, an alternative is the built-in `scroll-lock-mode`.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I applied your solution, but when I move by arrows, the position of current line changes and it is no more at the middle of screen.

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood your question then.  centered-cursor-mode will keep the *current* line in the centre.  When you move the cursor to another line, *that* line will be in the centre.

Comment: @Name: do you want to disable scrolling completely so that no matter where the cursor is (even hundreds of lines away) the selected line remains in the middle of the screen?

Comment: @redako yes exactly, I would like the selected line always remains in the middle of the screen.

Comment: @Name: disabling vertical scrolling altogether is rather extreme.  Would it not be acceptable to split the window in two (`C-x 2`) and scroll in one window while keeping the selected line in the other?

Comment: IMHO, `scroll-lock-mode` is *not* an alternative. It is broken. I loses centering in many cases, and doesn’t even try to re-center if you enter lines.

Comment: yes, ``scroll-lock-mode`` doesn't work as I would expect it. ``centered-cursor-mode`` works properly